# Python Pathlib Strange Behaviour

Tags: python, glob, pathlib

I can find all the files in the subfolders of a folder path with specific filetypes in this way:

```
list(Path(folder_path).glob('**/*.[jpg][jpeg][png]*'))
```

But if I change the code to try and find other filetypes (like `jfif` or `bmp`), with some filetypes the code works and with the others, it can't find the filepaths:

```
list(Path(folder_path).glob('**/*.[jpg][jpeg][jfif][png]*'))
```

Why isn't this code working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [pathlib docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.glob), the pattern syntax is the same as for [`fnmatch`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#module-fnmatch). A pattern like `[jpg]` matches a single character, which is either a `j`, a `p` or a `g`. I don’t think this type of pattern can handle alternatives — you have to use some other mechanism for filtering; something like `foo.suffix in [...]` or a regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Regex style "solution":

```py
from pathlib import Path
from re import search, IGNORECASE

folder_path = "."
images = r".*\.(jpg|jpeg|jfif|png)$"

files = list(filter(lambda f: search(images, str(f)), Path(folder_path).rglob("*")))
```